# Why does my converted html string only show the first line?

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have made an attempt att converting `html` code to an `attributed string` that is then used in a label. But for some reason it only shows the very first line: "Before proceeding:" All else is blank. I have extended the `label` constraints to fill the entire screen to make sure there's no issue with that. This `html` snippet has been tested for `android` and works fine.

```
let mystring = """
        <body>
            <p><b>Before proceeding:</b></p>
            <ul type="dash">
                <li>Save a backup copy of the door configuration file</li><li>Disconnect all other devices</li></ul>
            <p><b>During upgrade:</b></p>
            <ul type="dash">
                <li>Do not turn off phone</li>
            </ul>
            <p><b>Are you sure you want to upgrade?</b></p>
            </body>
        """

var attrString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = mystring.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
         return nil
    }
}
         
mylabel.attributedText = attrString
```

Is there anything that I have missed?

Comment: Did you set Number of Lines = 0 on your label?

Comment: omg thanks, that was it LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be entirely obvious, but...

At first it would seem that the `Number of Lines` property of a `UILabel` allows word-wrapping when the text is long enough.

However...

The `Number of Lines` property of a `UILabel` also controls the number of lines displayed, *even if the text has embedded newline characters*.

Setting `mylabel.numberOfLines = 0` will fix the issue.